# Get reference of baseview in a UIViewController iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

How to get reference to UIViewControllers baseview . I tried this

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

UIView *  baseView = keyWindow.rootViewController.view;
```

but in the baseView variable I am getting UILayoutContainerView instead of the view inside the UIViewController .Correct me if I am wrong somewhere .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AppDelegate's` `instance` to get `UIWindow` and then from it the `rootViewController` like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController = yourObjAppDelegate.window.rootViewController;

UIView *baseView = viewController.view;

NSLog(@"%@ : %@",viewController,baseView);
```